# Importing Transient Data into Paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview, geometry-surface

I have a 3D triangulated surface. `Nodes` and `Conn` variables store the coordinates and connectivity of the triangles. At each vertex, a scalar quantity, `S`, and a vector with three components, `V`, are stored. These data are time-dependent. Also, my geometry does not change over time and I have one surface for all the timesteps.

How should I approach for writing a VTK file that has the transient data over this surface? In other words, I want to write the value of `S` and `V` at different timestep on this 3D surface in a single VTK file. I ultimately want to import this VTK file into Paraview for visualization. `vtkTemporalDataSet` seems to be the solution for me but I could not find an example on how to write an ASCII or binary file for this VTK class. Could `vtkPolyData` somehow be used to define time so that Paraview knows the transient nature of my dataset? I would appreciate any help or comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VTK file format does not support transient data. However, you can write a series of files that ParaView will interpret as a time sequence. This will work fine with poly data in the VTK file. The file series is defined as files of the same name with a number identifier in them. For example, if you have a series of files named:

```
MyFile_000.vtk
MyFile_001.vtk
MyFile_002.vtk
```

ParaView will group these files together in its file browser and when you read them together, it will treat them as a file sequence with 3 time steps.

The bad part of this representation is that you will have to replicate the `Nodes` and `Conn` in each file. If that is a problem, you will have to use a different file format that supports multiple time steps using the same connection information (such as the Exodus II file format).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a converter in Matlab or Python for Exodus II file format?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no.